# Does storing the str.length() value in a variable before using it in a for loop have any performance improvements in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

In short, does the JVM internally optimize the following code

```
public void test(String str)
{
    int a = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a = a + str.length();
    }
}
```

to behave as efficiently as the one below:

```
public void test(String str)
{
    int len = str.length();
    int a = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        a = a + len;
    }
}
```

If it does optimize, does it do so by caching the str.length() value internally?

Comment: also note: `public int length() {return count;}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nice answer Elliot F.

I did a much simpler test and ran the two methods with a very large number of repetitions and timed each.

The first method (where the length is only calculated once) was consistently faster than the second method.

Here's the whole test class I created;

```
package _testing;

import java.util.Date;

public class Speed {

    long count = 5000000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start, finish; 
        Speed sp = new Speed(); 

        start = new Date().getTime();
        sp.test("test");
        finish = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println("test 1:"+(finish - start));

        start = new Date().getTime();
        sp.test2("test");
        finish = new Date().getTime();
        System.out.println("test 2:"+(finish - start));

    }


    public void test(String str) {
        int len = str.length();
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            a = a + len;
        }
    }

    public void test2(String str) {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            a = a + str.length();
        }
    }   
}
```

The output looks like this;

```
test 1:7
test 2:22
```

Comment: I really like that you wrote a benchmark. And it does suggest that it is a real measurable difference, **but** I will point out that you have *observed* a difference of `~(3/5000000) x` which doesn't strike me as statistically significant.

Comment: Shouldnt you incorporate the whole method in the loop, the "test()" gains an unfair advantage.

Answer (score 6):

I created the following two methods,

```
public void test(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a = a + len;
    }
}

public void test2(String str) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a = a + str.length();
    }
}
```

Then I used `javap -v` to generate for the first method `test`

```
  public void test(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=5, args_size=2
         0: aload_1
         1: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
         4: istore_2
         5: iconst_0
         6: istore_3
         7: iconst_0
         8: istore        4
        10: goto          20
        13: iload_3
        14: iload_2
        15: iadd
        16: istore_3
        17: iinc          4, 1
        20: iload         4
        22: bipush        10
        24: if_icmplt     13
        27: return
```

and for `test2`

```
  public void test2(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=4, args_size=2
         0: iconst_0
         1: istore_2
         2: iconst_0
         3: istore_3
         4: goto          17
         7: iload_2
         8: aload_1
         9: invokevirtual #16                 // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
        12: iadd
        13: istore_2
        14: iinc          3, 1
        17: iload_3
        18: bipush        10
        20: if_icmplt     7
        23: return
```

So the answer would seem to be there is some advantage to storing the length once (it produces shorter byte-code, equivalent to 23 vs 27 lines) which seems to suggest it *may* perform better, but I doubt it could actually be measured. Especially after the code has been JIT compiled).

Finally, you might consider

```
public void test(String str)
{
  int a = 0;
  for( int i = 0, len = str.length(); i < 10; i++) {
    a = a + len;
  }
}
```

or just

```
int a = 10 * str.length();
```

Comment: It does produce a shorter byte-code. But in test(..), does the runtime increase as a result of str.length() being calculated 10 times within the for loop?

Comment: @deepak In my finally comment? No. That `len` is set once before the loop begins; so it's equivalent to setting it outside the loop (but it is only in lexical scope for the loop body).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The question was for this:
public void test2(String str) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        a = a + str.length();
    }
}

Comment: @deepak I really doubt it would be measurable. Once the JIT has run on it you probably wouldn't see any actual difference either way. Try to [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html) and avoid trying micro-optimizations if you don't have the time or energy to test them completely in your environment.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch doesn't seem like you know what `if_icmplt` does. Otherwise you would know `invokevirtual` is happening many times, which is of course slower.

Comment: @gknicker See the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27497034/2970947), which directly benchmarks it. I will point out that the observed difference is approximately (3/5000000)

Comment: I like that you point out avoiding micro-optimizations, but personally I see this one as a "free optimization", that in my opinion, can add clarity in some cases. I don't think there's anything wrong with declaring a variable to hold that value as long as you're reasonable with scopes and so on, and I especially see nothing wrong with getting into the habit for times where `string.length()` is `someObject.someDeceptiveSometimesSlowCallThatOccassionallyChecksInOnTheCaymanIslands()`.